# HL7 V2.2 - SIU^S12

Tags: hl7-v2

I am using the SIU^S12 segment and I need to indicate the financial entity (IN1). But IN1 is not allowed in segment SIU^S12. Has anyone ever experienced this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You're right that financial information is not included in the SIU^S12 message, nor is it in the entire HL7v2 scheduling domain. I can't really attest to the "why" behind this, but only share my experience in the US domain.

From a very high level, in the United States, scheduling HL7v2 interfaces are used almost exclusively before the patient arrives, and ADT (HL7v2 Chapter 3) is used almost exclusively once the patient arrives. This is not ideal, and sometimes bears extra licensing costs in terms of getting two HL7v2 interfaces.

From a design perspective, I it makes sense to have a separation of concerns - SIU^S12 is chiefly concerned with scheduling resources - even treating patients as resources. SIU^S12 can have multiple patients in its schema, whereas ADT^A01 must have exactly one. While it would be possible to attach GT1, IN1/2/3 to each potential patient in SIU, it's easier to wrap your head around when only one patient is in play.

From a workflow perspective, insurance/payment information is typically verified with the patient in person once they arrive, so the majority of use cases won't need or more importantly trust insurance information were it to be sent by a scheduling system.